# Translating a none theme wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, translators

So I have website working on wordpress. A lot of the content is hard coded in the HTML and can not be edited in Wordpress via the pages screen. Meaning almost all the pages will show empty on the dashboard.

This is making it impossible to use translator plugins to translate the content. I was wondering on what is the best way of going about translating the site.

Google Translator is great, but is wrong. It is constantly getting words wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

Start by doing it right and move the content into the editor using the basic WordPress tools and maybe by adding custom fields (try Advanced Custom Fields) to make other content areas editable.

Once you have everything in WordPress you can start translating using plugins. There is not real other solution then this.